# Fourier Transform on varied time data

Tags: c#

So... no clue where I should be asking this question but I'm hoping someone here can at least point me in the right direction. I have a time series that I would like to do spectral analysis on but I can't find any tools for doing FFT that accommodate a varied time difference between data points (they all assume dt is constant). Does anyone know of a tool that would work for this (I'm specifically looking for a periodogram or some other way to determine periodicity).

My only thought is to do linear interpolation between data points at a specific time interval to give the data a constant dt but I'm worried that will scew the spectral analysis data.

Here is a small chunk of the data; time, data, dt

```
 time    data        dt
39.630  49662.1     0.170
39.810  49582.5     0.180
40.150  49430.0     0.340
40.320  49413.8     0.170
40.490  49324.0     0.170
40.670  49092.5     0.180
40.830  49025.6     0.160
41.010  49101.5     0.180
```

any suggestions??

Comment: Check the smallest difference in time between samples and then "virtualize" the data using that timespan and a linear interpolation as you said. Also, are you sure your data is right? where is it being captured from? can't you just sample it at constant rates?

Comment: Something list is best left for Matlab.  You can build a Matlab dll that can be accessed through Matlab.  Even if you don't use Matlab asking the question at their website may get a very good answer.

Comment: You are likely to get more answers @ http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most mathematical theory behind FFT requires a fixed sampling period. 
I can suggest you to do the following:

1. Create a sequence of equally spaced time instants
2. Calculate the value for each instant based on the neighbor points (linear or quadratic interpolation should do it). You can use as many points as you desire  in order to obtain the best approximation.
3. Depending on the degree of detail you want for your results use a parametric or non-parametric method for estimating spectrum: Burg method can be useful and LPC/AR model can also be useful.

Check the links at Mathworks:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/nonparametric-spectral-estimation.html

http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/parametric-spectral-estimation.html